# (How) can one visualise the derivative of the function $A \mapsto A^{-1}$, where $A$ is a matrix?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, derivatives, intuition, matrix-calculus

Our definition of differentiable is:

> Let $V$ and $W$ be Banachspaces, $V$ finite dimensional, and $G \subset V$ an open subset. We call a function $f: G \to W$ differentiable in $p \in G$ if there exists a linear map $F: V \to W$, so that for the remainder function $R:G \to W$, defined by
>   $$
> f(x) = f(p) + F(x - p) + R(x)
> $$
>   we have $\frac{R(x)}{\| x - p \|} \xrightarrow{x \to p} 0$.

Then, the function $F$ is unique and called the differential of $f$ in $p$, we write $F = D_p f$.

**Lemma:**
With all names from above we have for all $v \in V$
$$
F(v)
= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(p + tv) - f(p)}{t}
=: \partial_v f(p),
$$
if the limit exists and call it the directional derivative.

---

In our lecture we have shown the following

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional Banach-space, then the general linear group $$\mbox{GL}(V) := \{ A \in L(V, V): A \text{ is invertible } \}$$ is open in $L(V,V)$ and the mapping $$\mbox{inv}: \mbox{GL}(V) \to L(V,V), \quad A \mapsto A^{-1}$$ is differentiable and its derivative is $D_{A} \mbox{inv}(B) = - A^{-1} B A^{-1}$.

This is the case because
$$
\mbox{inv}(B) = \mbox{inv}(A) \underbrace{- A^{-1}(B - A)A^{-1}}_{D_A \text{inv}(B - A)} + \underbrace{A^{-1}(B - A)(A^{-1} - B^{-1})}_{= R(B)}.
$$

**Is there any way to visualise what $\mbox{inv}$ looks like and to picture its derivative?**

---

Using @RodrigodeAzevedo's hint, the [vector field](https://www.geogebra.org/m/u3xregNW) of a the inverse of a symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrix looks like this, but I don't really know what that "shows" me.
[image]

---

Comment: Didn't you switch $A$ and $B$ in $D_{A} \mbox{inv}(B)$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Nope. It's the derivative of inv(B) in the "point" A. Notice $D_p f(v) = \partial_v f(p)$ in out notation.

Comment: I believe you did. You have the directional derivative of $\mbox{inv}$ at $A$ in the direction of $B$. Or, $p = A$, $v = B$. Now check your notation again.

Comment: $\mbox{inv}(B)$ is a matrix, not a function. It has no derivative.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Well, a matrix is a linear map and therefore it's one derivative, right? Since we have $f(x) = f(p) + f(x - p) + 0$ for any linear map $f$.

Comment: Great. Your notation is still confusing and incorrect.

Comment: For symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrices, you can plot the vector field corresponding to $\mbox{inv}$.

Comment: Symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrices have $3$ degrees of freedom. Is $$\begin{bmatrix} x_{11}\\ x_{12}\\ x_{22}\end{bmatrix} \mapsto \frac{1}{x_{11} x_{22} - x_{12}^2}\begin{bmatrix} x_{22}\\ -x_{12}\\ x_{11}\end{bmatrix}$$ useful, however?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you for the idea, I included a plot in my post, but it still doesn't give me enough visualisation since in the tool I used an linked I can't insert anything else, for example the derivative (how would I do that) or a point where I want to evaluate the derivative.

Comment: I would say that attempting to visualize things is often utterly *hopeless*. I do not see a way of writing the directional derivative as an inner product in order to extract a gradient. You can try to visualize the scalar field from input matrix to a specific entry of the output matrix, but that only works for $1 \times 1$ matrices or symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrices.